# CSRF correlation in Gatling

Tags: javascript, regex, csrf, gatling

I need to correlate the CSRF_NONCE value from the response body of a gatling script.

```
PTC.flex.csrf.setNonceData('CSRF_NONCE', 'YSgUCGWgJBu8/Fm7I1k7MQuZR1PImDzVGWxSOxeYVUmIvRPuG2Nwfx/RR3WPnnLZDmx6cSvJYSaGzWyMVx8gPFKXEC2PxWONLER+SkrXT3OFkxvKKnhdcQPsU27bwWQ=');
```

I tried using the below regex check

```
.check(regex("""PTC.flex.csrf.setNonceData('CSRF_NONCE', '(\S[a-z]*[0-9]*[A-Z]*)');""").saveAs("CSRF1"))
```

but always getting the output as

```
"regex(PTC.flex.csrf.setNonceData('CSRF_NONCE', '(\S[a-z]*[0-9]*[A-Z]*)');).find.exists, found nothing"
```

Please suggest the correct way to give the expression.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, read [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to make question more readable. Also, you can read [«How to ask a good question»](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find more recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong.

Try

```
"""PTC\.flex\.csrf\.setNonceData\('CSRF_NONCE', '([a-z0-9A-Z=/\+]*)'\);"""
```

You can use https://regexr.com/ or write `"your regex".r.findAllMatchIn("your string")` in Scala to test your regex.